# Assigning probability values according to inversely proportional values.

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a question about assigning probability values according to inversely proportional values. The question in my homework is as follows:

A naturalist is observing the behavior of a frog in a small lily pond. There are four lily
pads in the pond, and the frog jumps from one to another. The probability of jumping
from any pad to another pad is inversely proportional to the relative distance. The matrix
shows the distances (see the distances table here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/46qGD.png).

Model the frog’s location as a Markov Chain. Provide the state definition and the state
space clearly. Provide the transition probability matrix.

My question is: How do I assign probability values considering the distances?

Answer (score 1):

The key is the inversely-proportional statement.

Here's an example: if you were at a given node and the other nodes were at distances of 1, 2, and 3 units away, then the probabilities of going to those nodes should be (respectively) $\frac 1 1, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 3$. However, that doesn't make sense because the total probability isn't 1, so we need to rescale these numbers. The total "probability" would have been $1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 = \frac{11}{6}$; hence, we can scale these down by a factor of $6/11$ to get something sensible. That is, the probabilities in that case should be $\frac{6}{11}, \frac{6}{22}, \frac{6}{33}$.

Comment: So if I consider the first leaf, distances to leaf 2,3 and 4 are 10, 20 and 15 respectively.  1/10 + 1/20 + 1/15 = 13/60. It is far less than 1. I don't know if I should consider whether frog stays on leaf 1, but nevertheless, I'm still confused. Should I assign the rest of the value to frog being on leaf 1, or do I misunderstand everything?

Comment: The "inversely proportional" part of this suggests that staying at the same location isn't an option, because we can't reciprocate $0$. So: take your 13/60, and inflate it up to 1 with a multiplicative constant as in the example above. Does this help?

**EDIT**: After re-reading the question, I'm actually not entirely clear that my interpretation about what to do with the "stay still" probability is reasonable. It's still my best guess, but you may want to check with your instructor.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, I managed to solve the question. And right, frog never stays still.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! Please consider accepting one of the answers here (either mine or Michael Smith's) so that this question can be marked as answered in the MSE system.

Answer (score 0):

The transition probabilities should be 1 divided by the distance given in the table, multiplied by a "lilypadspecific" constant that ensures that the sum of probabilities from each lilypad is one (given that the frog jumps in each period).

Comment: How do I get that constant?